# Adding PHP Line Spaces In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to write file but just need to work out best way to make some gaps/spaces between some code `“[‘default’][‘hostname’]” space . ‘=’ . space “‘localhost’”`can not work it out.

At the moment when reload page it produces `$db['default']['hostname']='localhost';` but need gap/space `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function index(){
  $output  = '<?php' . "\n";

  $output .= "\n";

  $output .= '// DB' . "\n";

  $output .= '$db' . "['default']['hostname']" space . '=' . space "'localhost'". ";" . "\n";

  $file = fopen(APPPATH . 'config/database-test.php', 'w');

  fwrite($file, $output);

  fclose($file);

  $this->load->view('welcome_message');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$output .= '$db' . "['default']['hostname']" space . '=' . space "'localhost'". ";" . "\n";`

This line has syntax errors because you're missing the concat operator before the first `space` and after the second one (whatever the space is meant to be).

Instead of complicating things, why don't you just write this and avoid the concat hell:

```
$output .= '$db' . "['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';\n";
```

Comment: When done this `$db_output .= '$db' . "['default']['hostname'] = '$this->request->post['db_localhost']';\n";` it produced `$db['default']['hostname'] = '->post['db_localhost']';` it should produce $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found answer to make gap `. " " .` seems to do the trick.

```
$output .= '$db' . "['default']['hostname']" . " " . '=' . " " . "'localhost'". ";" . "\n";
```

Comment: But why do you need to concat gaps?

Answer (score 0):

As an additional note, I see you are writing a config file to be processed later.

I have found output buffering and var_export to do this job exceptionally well.

```
ob_start();

var_export($config);

$out = ob_get_clean();
```

then

```
fwrite($f, '$config = '.$out.';'); etc...
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

basically this will turn an array into a parse-able string such as

```
array(
   'default'=>array(
        'hostname'=>'localhost',
        'user' => 'user', ///etc
    )
)
```

then just add the variable part and the ending semi-colon

if you plan to do multiple values this would be a much cleaner approach